# Trying to use Foundation's Orbit slider in Rails/Ember app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ember.js, zurb-foundation, orbit

I have a rails app that is using both the Ember and Foundation gems. All has been working as expected until I tried to use Foundation's Orbit slider -- http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/orbit.html.

The Foundation gem includes all of the js files in the body tag so both files I need -- foundation.js and foundation.orbit.js -- are there.

The only other instructions are to attach `data-orbit` to whatever element you want to slide through. Mine looks like:

```
<ul data-orbit>
  <li><img src="/assets/ewabout_1.jpg" class="carousel-pics"></li>
  <li><img src="/assets/ewabout_2.jpg" class="carousel-pics"></li>
  <li><img src="/assets/ewabout_3.jpg" class="carousel-pics"></li>
  <li><img src="/assets/ewabout_4.jpg" class="carousel-pics"></li>
  <li><img src="/assets/ewabout_5.jpg" class="carousel-pics"></li>
</ul>
```

But when I load the page the images are just stacked on top of one another, like the app can't find the javascript.

I feel like this is probably an ember issue, but I'm not sure. Is there something I need to add to the Ember View?

[image: App directory]

**UPDATE**

Changed `application.js` to the following and the slider renders, but multiplies bullets/buttons etc down the page resulting in the site crashing. But at least it gets the slider moving?

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require foundation
//= require handlebars
//= require ember
//= require_self
//= require ew
Ew = Ember.Application.create({
    ready: function () {
    setInterval(function() {
      $(document).foundation();
    }, 2000);
  }
});
```

Comment: ok, I just created another jsbin that loads correctly and updated my answer, sorry for the inconvenience, you can have a look now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But when I load the page the images are just stacked on top of one another, like the app can't find the javascript.

This is because you need to initialize the orbit plugin at the right moment, that is when the html markup has being rendered into the DOM, read along how to do it.

Basically what I've done was to create a `Ember.Component` *(but a view should also work)*, and put the orbit related markup directly in the component's template, then hook into the `didInsertElement` of the component and initialize the orbit plugin:

### orbit-slider component template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="components/orbit-slider">
    <ul data-orbit>
      <li><img src="http://placehold.it/400x240/#c2c2c9" class="carousel-pics"></li>
      <li><img src="http://placehold.it/400x240/#c2c2c9" class="carousel-pics"></li>
      <li><img src="http://placehold.it/400x240/#c2c2c9" class="carousel-pics"></li>
      <li><img src="http://placehold.it/400x240/#c2c2c9" class="carousel-pics"></li>
      <li><img src="http://placehold.it/400x240/#c2c2c9" class="carousel-pics"></li>
    </ul>
</script>
```

### orbit-slider component class:

```
App.OrbitSliderComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  initOrbit: function() {
    $(document).foundation('orbit', {
      animation: 'fade',
      timer_speed: 10000,
      pause_on_hover: true,
      resume_on_mouseout: false,
      animation_speed: 500,
      stack_on_small: true,
      navigation_arrows: true,
      slide_number: true,
      container_class: 'orbit-container',
      stack_on_small_class: 'orbit-stack-on-small',
      next_class: 'orbit-next',
      prev_class: 'orbit-prev',
      timer_container_class: 'orbit-timer',
      timer_paused_class: 'paused',
      timer_progress_class: 'orbit-progress',
      slides_container_class: 'orbit-slides-container',
      bullets_container_class: 'orbit-bullets',
      bullets_active_class: 'active',
      slide_number_class: 'orbit-slide-number',
      caption_class: 'orbit-caption',
      active_slide_class: 'active',
      orbit_transition_class: 'orbit-transitioning',
      bullets: true,
      timer: true,
      variable_height: false,
      before_slide_change: function(){},
      after_slide_change: function(){}
    });
  }.on('didInsertElement')
});
```

### usage in template

```
...
{{orbit-slider}}
...
```

As you can see I've used all possible configuration possibilities just to be sure it works, but of course you can omit them or change them accordingly.

Here a working demo: http://jsbin.com/iciDiPI/2/edit

Hope it helps.

Comment: How would you add content to that component dynamically, e.g a array with values or a hash?

Comment: Thanks so much for this. I'm working to implement it now. I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: I know this is probably a dumb question but since I'm using a structured directory to organize my ember app where should I put `App.OrbitSliderComponent`? I created a `components` directory for `orbit_slider_component.js` and then put `orbit-slider.hbs` inside of templates/components. But the slider still isn't working. I'll attach a screenshot to my original question.

Comment: @reknirt, sorry for the delay. Had a busy day, will look at it tomorrow - I promise :)

Comment: Thank you! You've been a huge help.

Comment: @intuitivepixel So I added a ready property to `Ember.Application.create();` and the slider begins to work. Problem is every time it slides it is multiplying the bullets and next and prev arrows until the page essentially crashes. Does this help you at all? I'll add the code above.

Comment: why do you have the `setInterval`? the behaviour you are seeing is normal reinitializing foundation every 2 seconds.

Comment: Right. But when I get rid of `setInterval` the slider fails to initialize.

Comment: @reknirt, then try using `setTimeout` instead, or better `Ember.run.later` with the same millis

Comment: That did it. Thank you. Why do you think that is required to initialize the js?

Comment: @reknirt, I guess because foundation is also a framework it needs to do some kind of initialization stuff before it can work, and this initialization has to happen when the DOM is ready, I guess it would also work doing the foundation call in something like `$(document).ready(function() { $(document).foundation(); });` even without the `setTimeout`

Comment: Thanks again for all your help. I very much appreciate it.

Comment: @intuitivepixel Any idea why I have to hit the refresh button when I visit the /about page to get the slider working? When I navigate to that page from index the images are stacked, but when I hit refresh and it reloads that specific page the slider works.