# How do I show a spinning gif while just loading images in the templates/views, not actual data?

Tags: ember.js

I have an ember site that is mostly static. However many of the pages have large high res images and image sliders that sometimes flicker when you navigate to a new page for the first time or load the site for the first time.

I was curious if its possible to use this feature: http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/found-a-fun-hidden-loading-feature/1677/5 on just images, not actual data from a server?

I created `loading_route.js` with one line:

```
Ew.LoadingRoute = Ember.Route.extend({});
```

And I created `loading.hbs` but nothing is happening.

Thanks!

Comment: seeing this question and the problem you have with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18992613/trying-to-use-foundations-orbit-slider-in-rails-ember-app other question it seems there myght be something going on in your process build process that does not parses you template nor routes folders correctly?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that with a `Loading Route` - but I don't see a reason why you can't do that using jQuery?